# Angular - Responsive Tabs with Dropdown

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, tabs

I currently have the following code (Example below), where I'm hiding and moving Tabs into a Dropdown Menu, based on the available width. So far, everything has worked out nicely. Now however, the user needs to open the Dropdown Menu (if there is an Active Tab in there), to show the currently selected Tab.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkd1t2?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftabs%2Ftabs.component.ts

I would like to exclude the Active Tab from hiding and place it directly before the Dropdown Menu Toggle ("More"), so the user can immediately see which Tab is currently selected. I hope the screenshots below are helpful to give you a better picture of what I'm trying to achieve.

[State 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4y7m.png) -> [State 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMRJS.png)

I've already tried excluding the Active Tab from `hiddenItems` within my `primaryItems.forEach()` Method but didn't get it to work. Should I use the `Array.splice()` Method for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by replacing the "More" Text with the Selected Tab Text, if the Active Tab (Index) is within hiddenItems. Otherwise the default "More" Text will be used.

This is not exactly what I was trying to achieve initially but probably the easiest and cleanest solution for now.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymtu1c?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftabs%2Ftabs.component.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, hey! I checked your codes and to solve it was tough with your way because `@HostListeners` got many updates to listen changes. There are so many other solutions that we used to. With an effective way, you won't reach what you want, I meant with the *clean way*. When you change of your elements' hidden option, your app will forget that they were hidden. Listeners will catch a change and your app will re-render tab components. And of course they will collect displayed components and hide them again because of gap.

I will give you the *dirty solution*;

We need variables as a contemporary dataset.

```
...
  resizeTimeout: number; 
 
  displayed_data: number[] = [];
  dataOfHiddens: number[] = [];
...
```

At the end of `renderTabs` function, you should add these to save our last informations.

```
...

    this.activeIndexIsHidden = hiddenItems.includes(this.activeIndex);
    this.dataOfHiddens = hiddenItems;
    this.displayed_data = displayedItems;
  }
}
```

Add `displayedItems` to track pushes.

```
const hiddenItems: number[] = [];
const displayedItems: number[] = [];
```

Then when you call primary items for each, you should modify to lead how they act in every frame. We can call this filtering. I split conditions on purpose.

```
primaryItems.forEach((item: HTMLElement, index: number) => {

 //FIND ACTIVE INDEX WAS HIDDEN?
  if (this.dataOfHiddens.includes(this.activeIndex)) {
    //FROM NOT HIDDEN TABS, FIND MAX INDEX AND BIGGERS TO HIDE
    let ind = Math.max(...this.displayed_data);
    if (index >= ind && this.activeIndex != index) {
      item.classList.add('tabs__item--hidden');
      item.querySelector('button').setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
      hiddenItems.push(index);
    }
  } else if ( //CHECK DATA IF TAB WAS HIDDEN
    this.dataOfHiddens.includes(index) &&
    index != this.activeIndex
  ) { //IF IT'S, HIDE AGAIN TO AVOID LISTENERS
    item.classList.add('tabs__item--hidden');
    item.querySelector('button').setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
    hiddenItems.push(index);
  } else if (
    primaryWidth - safetyOffset >=
    stopWidth + item.offsetWidth + flexGap
  ) {
    stopWidth += item.offsetWidth + flexGap;
    //IF NO RULE TO HIDE, SEND THEM TO DISPLAYED LIST
    displayedItems.push(index);
  } else {
    //FOR RE-RENDER DON'T HIDE ACTIVE INDEX RULE!
    if (this.activeIndex != index) {
      item.classList.add('tabs__item--hidden');
      item.querySelector('button').setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
      hiddenItems.push(index);
    }
  }
});
```

You should check some other stuff you can handle. Tested, works well. For any questions, comment below.

Comment: Hey, thank you for taking your time! I have solved it now differently, by replacing the "More" Text with the "Active Tab" Text. I think this is the "cleanest" and easiest solution without having to move around everything. 

You are right about the HostListeners, most of them are necessary for accessibility though. I will post my solution below separately.